# Using ORM outside of laravel cannot find my test model "User"

Tags: php, class, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to workd without Laravel for little project but using Eloquent component. But always is throwing me the error "**Fatal error: Class 'AutoDev\Models\User' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AutoDev\index.php on line 7**".

Here is the structure of this test project:

```
-AutoDev(root) [
  index.php,
  init.php,
  composer.json
  app [
    models [
      User.php
    ]
  ]
  vendor [
    all the staff
  ]
```

and here is the code code:

---

**Index.php**

```
<?php

require 'init.php';

use AutoDev\Models\Users as Users;

$users = Users::all();
var_dump($users);
```

**init.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' =>'mysql',
    'host' => 'autodev',
    'database' => 'database',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'db0305',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
]);

$capsule->setAsGlobal();

$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

**compser.json**

```
{
"require": {
    "illuminate/database": "*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AutoDev\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

**autoload-ps4.php**

```
    <?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return [
    'Symfony\\Component\\Translation\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/translation'),
    'Stringy\\' => array($vendorDir . '/danielstjules/stringy/src'),
    'Illuminate\\Support\\' => array($vendorDir . '/illuminate/support'),
    'Illuminate\\Database\\' => array($vendorDir . '/illuminate/database'),
    'Illuminate\\Contracts\\' => array($vendorDir . '/illuminate/contracts'),
    'Illuminate\\Container\\' => array($vendorDir . '/illuminate/container'),
    'AutoDev\\' => array($baseDir . '/app'),
];
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace AutoDev\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Users extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = "users";
    protected $guarded = "*";
    protected $primaryKey = 'u_id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'u_user',
        'u_pass',
        'u_matrix',
        'u_sponsor',
        'u_activate',
        'u_state'
    ];

}
```

Well, this test project  should work like that (I did the same that other examples on internet) however doesn't.

What is missing? I can't fix it.

Comment: You are likely to get a better response if you paste the text of your code into your question rather than screen shots.

Comment: well, I thought screenshots was the best way to read the code. That's all the code I got.

Comment: If someone wants to try to replicate your problem, and you have provided screen shots, they would have to retype your code. They are unlikely to bother. If you copy and paste text, you are likelier to get an answer.

Comment: No body knows what it going on with my that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The file User.php, it wasn't a php file, just "User", no extensions...